Wrap long C++ function heads with clang-format
I just started to use clang-format and I could set up quite a lot of things, but I am stuck with my general handling of long function headers. This is how I usually create them:
void myLongFunctionOrMethod(
    int one,
    float two,
    std::string three,
    ...whatever
) {
    Do something
    ...
}

To me, this is the cleanest and most maintainable style. Is there a way to enforce this in clang-format? I prefer not to place braces on the next line for various reasons, but I find it best when the (outer) indentation level clearly indicates where the body begins.

Without diving in, there's certainly a maybe as an answer. The flip side is that once you bring in a formatter, you do have to be willing to give up some of your preferences.

There are lots of online tools to test clang format options. Try one of those, for example: https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ there by default brace opening function is not wrapped.

@sweenish, yes I know I have to give up some of my expectations. But if there is an opportunity not to give it up... :)
It is just strange, that noone needs this formatting style

@MarekR, nice page, thanks.

Try for example: BasedOnStyle: Chromium

---
Language:        Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
BinPackParameters: false

This combination of settings should do what you want.
Before:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void myLongFunctionOrMethod(int one, float two, std::string three, int four,
                            int five, int six, int seven) {
  std::cout << "Hi.\n";
}

int main() {}

After:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void myLongFunctionOrMethod(
    int one,
    float two,
    std::string three,
    int four,
    int five,
    int six,
    int seven
) {
  std::cout << "Hi.\n";
}

int main() {}

This was tested using clang-format version 18.1.6 (Fedora 18.1.6-3.fc40).

The indentation level is still off. Code and parameter are on the same level in the target format. Maybe with IndentWidth: 4 or ContinuationIndentWidth: 4?

OP is free to play with as many other options as they wish to get things just right. But the settings above are the minimum required to get the layout they want.

@sweenish Thanks, this does not work on my version, but I'll upgrade my whole system in some weeks, so we'll see.

@sweenish, Upgraded my system to Debian 12 and clang-format 14 already has this feature.
